# Rails 4 LocalJumpError for nested recourse form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, friendly-id

I have a nested recourse called "transactions" inside another recourse "budgets".

All I'm trying to accomplish is for my users to be able to edit individual "transactions". However when I go to /1/transactions/1/edit I get a LocalJumpError saying "no block given (yield)".
There might be a very simple solution to this but I haven't been able to find it yet.

**routes.rb**:

```
resources :budgets, :path => '/' do
  resources :transactions
end
```

**budget.rb:**

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions

  validates :amount, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :amount, numericality: true

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record?
  end
end
```

**transaction.rb**

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :budget

  validates :amount, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :budget, presence: true
  validates :date, presence: true
  validates :amount, numericality: true
  validates :is_positive, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
end
```

**transactions_controller.rb**

```
  def edit
    @budget = Budget.friendly.find(params[:budget_id])
    @transaction = @budget.transaction
  end
```

And in the view **transactions/edit.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming a model Transaction conflicts with ActiveRecord::Transactions. You'll need to rename your model.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I would have never guessed that. Thank you very much